# how to give time delay for mouseover

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, mouseover

I have a following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //When mouse rolls over
    $("#nav #nav_li").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'140px', width:'182px'},{queue:false, duration:600})
    });

    //When mouse is removed
    $("#nav #nav_li").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'11px', width:'146px'},{queue:false, duration:900})
    });


});
```

In that when i do mouse over its suddenly animate works

when i hover the #nav_li it will animate after few seconds

Thank you folks

Comment: Do you have the `nav_li` ID used more than once?

Comment: Sorry, I really can't understand what you are saying.

Comment: @Nick Craver: yes i have used

Comment: IDs need to be unique, you can't have it occur more than once in your page, for those use `class="mav_li"` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is [jQuery plugin HoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) to deal with that issue.

> overIntent is a plug-in that attempts
>   to determine the user's intent... like
>   a crystal ball, only with mouse
>   movement! It works like (and was
>   derived from) jQuery's built-in hover.
>   However, instead of immediately
>   calling the onMouseOver function, it
>   waits until the user's mouse slows
>   down enough before making the call.
>
> Why? To delay or prevent the
>   accidental firing of animations or
>   ajax calls. Simple timeouts work for
>   small areas, but if your target area
>   is large it may execute regardless of
>   intent.